# SpringBoot/Swagger: Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

i am getting the following error after i start my spring boot application including swagger:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DelegatingLinkRelationProvider and org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>de.coerdevelopment</groupId>
<artifactId>higherlower</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>HigherLowerServer</name>
<description>HigherLowerServer</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Some suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Remove the `spring-plugin-core` dependency.

Comment: this also didn't worked to me :(

Comment: Make sure you are also using a compatible swagger version (as that will pull in Spring stuff as well).

Comment: Can you execute `mvn dependency:tree` and include the output to the question?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Spring-Boot, I suggest using the `springfox-boot-starter` dependency with the latest version in your project.

Delete `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui` from your dependencies and add this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```